# Convert tuple to numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, raspberry-pi, tuples

I'm developping a small script in image treatment in python which running on raspberry PI. I have a problem about the variable type. I have two functions. The first one is a function that converts an RGB image to binary, which works:

```
img_bw = cv2.threshold(img_filtered,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

The second function allows me to clean the pixel less than 300px

```
img_morph = morphology.binary_opening(img_bw,ones((9,5)),iterations=2)
```

The result when I try to execute:

```
*input = numpy.asarray(input)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 235, in
  asarray return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.*
```

According to some research in the forum, I understood the problem is about the type of the variable. The type of `img_bw` is a `tuple` type and the second function needs a variable of type `ndarray`. I didn't find a correct syntax that allow me to convert `tuple` to `ndarray`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Questions should be posted in English please...

Comment: @Ben: minus "please", it's actually a must. This is unsalvagable.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, no need to be impolite, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in French

Comment: I will post it in english as soon as possible. I just need help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @cel: I did not mean to be impolite. LamineBA: Looking forward to your english version!

Comment: I will post it soon. I try to post it in the comment.

Comment: I'm developping a small script in image treatment in python which rennuin in the raspberry PI. 
I have a problem about the variable type. 
I have two functions : 
The first one is a function that convert an RGB image to binary
img_bw = cv2.threshold(img_filtered,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) [OK]

Comment: The second function allow me to clean the pixel less than 300px
img_morph = morphology.binary_opening(img_bw,ones((9,5)),iterations=2) [NOK]

Comment: The result when I try to execute : input = numpy.asarray(input) in asarray return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: According to some research in the forum, I understood the problem is about the type 
of the variable. The type of (img_bw) is a tuple type and the second 
function need a variable which type is ndarray.
I didn't find a correct syntax that allow me to convert tuple to ndarray. 
Thank you

Comment: please edit your question and replace your version by the english one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cv2.threshold` itself retuns a tuple, that you can properly assign as follows

```
retval, img_bw = cv2.threshold(img_filtered,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

your original code `img_bw = cv2.threshold(img_filtered,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` assigns the tuple to `img_bw`.

See the documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the link [http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html] is not accesible. Please recheck the link.

Comment: The correct link is http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html
Thank you @wolfrevo.
When you use img_bw = cv2.threshold(img_filtered,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY), python will automatically assign a type tuple to img_bw. And when you use retval, img_bw = cv2.threshold(img_filtered,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY), retval is a float type and img_bw is a numpy.ndarray type.
Thank you again

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I've updated the answer. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as answered.